# Join Maps in Rdd of tuples

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have one single RDD in the form of:
`nameResolvedFromHashes: RDD[(Node, String, Option[String], Option[String], Map[String, String])]`

My RDD's sample data looks like this:

```
(<MyXml1>,{MyJson1},Some(1),Some(2),Map(hash1 -> value1))
(<MyXml1>,{MyJson1},Some(1),Some(2),Map(hash2 -> value2))
(<MyXml2>,{MyJson2},Some(3),Some(4),Map(hash3 -> value3))
```

I want to get something like this,i.e. join the tuples _5 element's maps if the 1st 4 elements are the same.

Output:

```
(<MyXml1>,{MyJson1},Some(1),Some(2),Map(hash1 -> value1,hash2 -> value2))
(<MyXml2>,{MyJson2},Some(3),Some(4),Map(hash3 -> value3))
```

I tried:

```
nameResolvedFromHashes.map(tup => ((tup._1,tup._2,tup._3,tup._4), tup._5)).reduceByKey { case (a, _) => a }.map(_._2)
```

But it gave only line 2 and 3 of my input as output. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the logic of your `reduceByKey` -> `map` step. Using a single `reduceByKey` to sum the maps seems to accomplish your goal. Is there something I'm missing?

```
scala> val in = Seq(("a", "b", 1, 2, Map((1 -> "c"))),("a", "b", 1, 2, Map((2 -> "d"))),("e", "f", 1, 2, Map((1 -> "g"))))
in: Seq[(String, String, Int, Int, scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String])] = List((a,b,1,2,Map(1 -> c)), (a,b,1,2,Map(2 -> d)), (e,f,1,2,Map(1 -> g)))

scala> val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(in)
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String, Int, Int, scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String])] = ParallelCollectionRDD[14] at parallelize at <console>:25

scala> val done = rdd.map(tup => ((tup._1,tup._2,tup._3,tup._4), tup._5)).reduceByKey { _ ++ _ }.map(tup => (tup._1._1, tup._1._2, tup._1._3, tup._1._4, tup._2)).map{case ((a, b, c, d), e) => (a,b,c,d,e)}`
done: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String, Int, Int, scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String])] = ShuffledRDD[16] at reduceByKey at <console>:25

scala> done foreach println
(a,b,1,2,Map(1 -> c, 2 -> d))
(e,f,1,2,Map(1 -> g))
```

Comment: You are Almost Correct, however just the reduce is giving me the tuple `((... , .., ...),Map)`
I need it as `(...,...,...,Map)`

e.g: your output's 1st line should look like: `(a,b,1,2,Map(1 -> c, 2 -> d))`